# Single-word term for "business name"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for the **name of a business**. The word "*business*" itself is not appropriate for me as it designates the entity and not the name itself. The word "*name*" is too generic, just like "*title*".

Comment: So, what's wrong with "business name"?

Comment: Let's say I already have used "business name" a few times and want to diversify the vocabulary.

Comment: Use a pronoun, or shorten it to *name*. Introducing a different term entirely instead might actually confuse the reader. One term for one thing is enough.

Comment: It's kinda tricky to shorten to just "name" because I'm also mentioning "product name". I'm also ambivalent about using a pronoun in this case.

Comment: Try and include a use case (example) sentence with context.

Comment: "Company" or "Entity" (in context) should be readily understandable.

Comment: "Diversifying the vocabulary" merely for the sake of variety is generally deprecated in English stylistics; see ["elegant variation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation).

Comment: @StoneyB thank you for the instructive link on "Elegant variation". The contrasting difference with French is enlightening. I'm now considering a restructure of a few paragraphs altogether, although I'd still be interested if someone comes up with a good term.

Comment: @StoneyB I've read a little about Henry Watson Fowler and understand his point. But I still don't much care for writing which repeats the same words *ad nauseam*. This is perhaps why writing is regarded as an art not a science.

Comment: "Noun-ize" DBA?

Answer (score 1):

How about using **brand**?

Brand is the name that identifies one seller's product distinct from those of other sellers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **[trade name](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/trade%20name)**

> 1. A name used to identify a commercial product or service, which may or may not be registered as a trademark. Also called brand name.
> 2. The name by which a commodity, service, or process is known to the trade.
> 3. The name under which a business firm operates.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with [label](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label).  Many companies use this along with brand.  Label though sounds less jargony.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *identity* to refer to the business name.

> **identity**: the individual characteristics by which a thing or person is known or recognized.